# Simcity Epic Projects

Tags: simcity-2013

How do you produce the lawnmower, ladder, paint, etc. to get your tokens for epic projects?  I've just unlocked/upgraded to this section and it is really cool but I have no way to finish without these items.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to fast track those particular items. They are unlocked at certain levels so if you aren't there yet, you won't be able to produce them. If you have reached the required level but the items are still unavailable, check to be sure that the commercial building itself does not require an upgrade. Some items become available upon doing so. Good luck!